# Issue after pip update to version 9.0.1 (on Ubuntu 10.04)

Tags: python, python-2.7, pip

I have a python 2.7.12 installed on ubuntu 10.04. I have updated **pip** from 8.1.2 to the last version (9.0.1) but now when I run pip (for example `pip freeze` or any other command) I get this error:

```
 Traceback (most recent call last):

 File "/usr/local/bin/pip", line 11, in <module>
    sys.exit(main())
 File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/__init__.py", line 233, in main
    return command.main(cmd_args)
 File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/basecommand.py", line 251, in main
    timeout=min(5, options.timeout)) as session:
 File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/basecommand.py", line 72, in _build_session
    insecure_hosts=options.trusted_hosts,
 File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/download.py", line 329, in __init__
    self.headers["User-Agent"] = user_agent()
 File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/download.py", line 93, in user_agent
    from pip._vendor import distro
 File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/_vendor/distro.py", line 1050, in <module>
    _distro = LinuxDistribution()
 File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/_vendor/distro.py", line 594, in __init__
    if include_lsb else {}
 File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/_vendor/distro.py", line 933, in _get_lsb_release_info
    raise subprocess.CalledProcessError(code, cmd, stdout)
subprocess.CalledProcessError: Command 'lsb_release -a' returned non-zero exit status 1
```

After read the traceback I have tried to execute the command `lsb_release -a` and it returns: `ImportError: no module named lsb_release`

Any ideas to solve this issue?

Answer (score 1):

The issue exists on multiple Ubuntu versions (16.04, 16.10 for certain) as well as yours.

Even a basic `pip list -o` fails (this will confirm the condition).

It is worth noting that the OS python and self-install modules can be problematic so proceed at your own "risk".

Remove current **pip**:

```
sudo su - 
pip uninstall pip
```

Get **pip** installer:

```
wget https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py
```

(Re)Install **pip**:

```
python get-pip.py
```

Update all eggs:

```
for i in `pip list -o --format legacy|awk '{print $1}'` ; do pip install --upgrade $i; done
```

Comment: Once you start using pip, isn't it better to start learning about virtual envs? Then you can manage all your Python packages independantly from the OS packages, and each can work alongside flawlessly.

Comment: Without question, imo the right way to go is using env's. As the OP didn't frame the post around it, to answer his help request I provided the generic approach.